# Dreadful performance of MoveNext inside class implementing IEnumerable<T>

Tags: .net, ienumerable, enumeration

I've got a wrapper class that's used in an MVC application that is designed to loop through the items in a collection and check that the current user has authorisation to access that item before returning it for display. For the most part it works like a charm. However for one particular object type it runs like an absolute dog and I can't work out why.

The Interface classes are written like this:

```
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _ViewData;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (T item in _viewData)
        {
            if (item.UserCanEdit || item.UserCanView)
                yield return item;
        }
    }


    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
         return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Now my first question is check my understanding of what's going on here. I'm probably wrong, but my understanding is that when I try and run a foreach loop against a collection of type objects it never needs to use System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() - certainly that code never gets hit?

The problem lies when I try and use this wrapper on log file entries, which are delivered via entity framework in a LogEntryViewDaya class. When the code hits the foreach loop inside GetEnumerator it stop for a full 6-8 seconds, even though there are only 20 items in the enumeration!

Here's the code for LogEntryView

```
public class LogEntryViewData:BaseViewData
{
    private LogEntry _entry;
    public LogEntryViewData(LogEntry entry, ICustomerSecurityContext securityContext) : base(securityContext)
    {
        _entry = entry;
    }

    public string Application { get { return _entry.Application; } }
    public string CurrentUser { get { return _entry.CurrentUser; } }
    public string CustomerName { get { return _entry.CustomerName; } }
    public DateTime Date { get { return _entry.Date; } }
    public string Exception { get { return _entry.Exception; } }
    public string HostName { get { return _entry.HostName; } }
    public long Id { get { return _entry.Id; } }
    public string Level { get { return _entry.Level; } }
    public string Message { get { return _entry.Message; } }
    public int? ProcessId { get { return _entry.ProcessId; } }
    public int? ServiceId { get { return _entry.ServiceId; } }
    public string ServiceName { get { return _entry.ServiceName; } }
    public int? TaskId { get { return _entry.TaskId; } }
    public int? TaskName { get { return _entry.TaskName; } }
    public string Thread { get { return _entry.Thread; } }
}
```

As far as I can tell there's no appreciable performance in instantiating these classes - putting a breakpoint in the constructor and F5ing through seems slick as anything.

So why is a collection of these particular objects so slow to iterate through? I have no idea: suggestions gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown us how the class is being populated. My *guess* is that the time is going on database queries - in particular, depending on what's being fetched, it's just possible that there's one query to get the skeletal entities, and then one query for *each* of `UserCanEdit` and `UserCanView`. That seems unlikely (I'd have expected the entry to have those properties populated on the initial query) but just possible.

Basically, watch how it's interacting with your database.

I suggest you try to write a console app which uses the same class, so you can mess around with it, add timing logs etc more easily than you can from a webapp.

EDIT: Aside from everything else in the comments etc, is there any reason you're not doing this as part of a LINQ query? For example:

```
var query = db.LogEntries.Where(x => x.UserCanEdit || x.UserCanView);
```

I appreciate it probably won't be quite as simple as that, as `UserCanEdit` will depend on the current user etc - but it probably *should* be done as a database query rather than client-side.

Comment: Okay, going to show my ignorance here but I had assumed the class was populated when its constructor was called? That's happening before it ever gets to the foreach loop and seems to be occurring at a satisfactory speed.

Comment: @Matt: Well you've passed in an `IEnumerable<T>`, but that could be lazily evaluated. In particular, if you're passing in an `IQueryable<T>` then you're effectively passing in the *query* rather than the results of evaluating that query. Aside from anything else, you could change your constructor to call `ToList()` and store that list, which would force the query to be executed. Basically we can't see enough code here to know what's going on.

Comment: @Matt: Well maybe... or maybe it's whatever's *calling* the constructor. You're the one who knows what the rest of the system is doing... I go back to my suggestion of writing a short console app which will let you test this in a simple manner. Put logs of logging in, and trace where the database is being hit (and how long that takes).

Comment: @Matt: Ah, you've removed/edited the comment I was replying to. Currently we don't know how your "interface class" is being constructed, or what any of the rest of the code is doing. What is the implementation of `_ViewData` here? (If you put a breakpoint in your GetEnumerator method, what does `_ViewData.GetType()` return?)

Comment: Sorry, I edited it because I realised I was just further showing my stupidity. The GetType() call returns {Name = "<TakeIterator>d__3a`1" FullName = "System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[[ViewData.ApplicationLog.LogEntryViewData, <edit>, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType} .. I removed a couple of sensitive namespaces in that ;)

Comment: @Matt: Okay, so that looks like you're calling `Take(...)` on something higher up... now it depends on what else it's iterating over. If you call `_ViewData.ToList()`, how long does that take, and what does it do to the database?

Comment: Aha, yes that's where the hit is. I'll fire up SQL profiler and take a look.

Comment: Okay at this point you get a tick because you've helped me work toward a solution and I've been behaving like an idiot. I've found out what the problem is now: expanding that Enumerable executes a query that returns 98,000 rows of data ... just not sure how to fix it since it's auto-generated by entity framework :)

Comment: @Matt: I suspect the problem is that you're calling Take (and possibly other things) on something with a compile-time type of `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>`. Anything you call on `IEnumerable<T>` will be performed client-side instead of in SQL.

Comment: No, as it turns out the problem is that I'm *not* calling Take(). And in actual fact I can't in order to achieve what I need to do for reasons that are too obscure to explain here. But basically I was misunderstanding how LINQ works - in trying to do "foreach" on what was supposed to only be 20 objects I had neglected to realise that without Take() it was being forced to process the entire collection (of 98,000 objects) in order to get the top 20! D'oh!